# elements of conjugacy classes of each of $D_4, Q_8 , S_n , A_n $

Tags: group-theory

Enumerate the elements of conjugacy classes of each of $D_4, Q_8 , S_n , A_n $ for n$\le$6.

my question:
is there a quick way to deal with this question?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no quick way to deal with the question. If the cases $S_n$ and $A_n$ are particular in a general group $G$ it is complicated. However, here is a first list of properties that can help you:

1. Two conjugate elements have the same order.
2. Two conjugate elements have the same image  through the abelianization (i.e. they represent the same element in $G/[G,G]$).
3. For $g,h\in G$ two elements that are not conjugate, there exists a representation in some $(\rho,V)$ such that $tr(\rho(g))\neq tr(\rho(h))$.

For $D_4$ and $Q_8$ the argument $2$ alone allows you to conclude.

Comment: Yipes! We don't need representations to get through these examples. The first two can be done by brute force. For the second, you must have some theorem on when two elements in $S_n$ are conjugate, yes? (Hard to know what you have and haven't seen based on your question.)

Comment: @JohnBrevik, I agree with you brute force + theorem for the symmetric group. However OP's question is, in my opinion, how to deal with conjugacy classes in general...